# Difference between int variable and int data

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++.

What is difference between int variable and int data? Are variable type and data type the same?

Comment: If I understand, a *variable type* --  the type can be `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, etc... (and their unsigned counterparts) These are generally referred to a fundamental types inherited from C. (C++ introduces a number of new container types through the Standard Template Libarary, but we will leave that for later). A *variable*, for lack of better words, is an instance of one of the types. Such as `int foo;` The type is `int` and the variable name is `foo`. (storage is reserved for `foo` in the program stack). Another important aspect of type is ***type controls pointer arithmetic***.

Answer (score 3):

Their relation like water glass and water. The variable is a water glass it can hold water. The data is water itself.

An int variable is an area in memory that can hold integer data.

int data is like 1,2,3... you can assign it to int variable.

Comment: I like the imagery, nice "visualisation".

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank you. Beginners need simple explanations otherwise they will get more confused.

Answer (score 2):

The expressions "variable type" and "data type" are used interchangeably.
There is however a difference between "variable" and "data".

A non-compound (i.e. not array, struct, vector, list...) variable can hold one piece of data of a given type. That data can and usually will change during execution of a program. I.e. it can contain different data of the type, but not at the same time.

When mentioning "data", people usually refer to larger amounts, like all the data read from an input file. Often an input variable is involved which, one after another, will hold all parts of the input. Similar for output, a program can generate lots of output data, with little or even no input.